# Cordova Vibration is not working when getting notification through firebase

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

Hi I am working in application where it receives push notification. Every thing is working fine but i am not getting VIBRATION when notificaton comes. please help how do i solve this error??

My php Code

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' );
$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'body'  => $_GET['body'],
    'title'     => $_GET['title'],
    'vibrate'   => true,
    'sound'     => true,
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'                  => $msg,
        'notification'      => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close($ch);
//echo $result;
echo json_encode(array("data"=>$msg));
?>
```

My Code

```
FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){


            if(data.wasTapped){

                            //alert( JSON.stringify(data.title) );
                             if(data.title=="New Order"){

                            //     alert("->"+data.body);
                                 localStorage.setItem("orderr", JSON.stringify(data.body));
                                window.location="new_order.html";
                                 }
                        }else{

                        //  alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
                          if(data.title=="New Order"){
                        //    alert("->"+data.body);

                                 localStorage.setItem("orderr", JSON.stringify(data.body));
                                 window.location="new_order.html";

                          }
                        }

                      },
                      function(msg){
                          //alert('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
                      },
                      function(err){
                        //  alert('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
                      }
                    );

                     function onBackKeyDown() {
                alert("Can't Go Back");

            //navigator.app.backHistory();
            // window.location="main.html";
            }

            };
```

Comment: And where do you trigger the vibration?

Comment: I trigger vibration in my php file

Comment: This makes no sense to me, care to explain ?